# jedis psubscribe causes application to hang

Tags: java, redis, freeze, jedis

I'm using redis 2.8.19 and jedis 2.6.0

```
pool = new JedisPool( new JedisPoolConfig(), "ip", 6379, 0 );
        System.out.println( "test2" );
        Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();
        jedis.psubscribe( new KeyExpiredListener(), "__key*__:*" );
        pool.returnResource( jedis );
        System.out.println( "test3" );
```

output:

```
test2
```

The app seems to hang when i try to subscribe to a channel. So the question I pose is why is my application hanging because of this.

Comment: Please don't make folks guess what your question might be.

Comment: Well, I was wondering what would cause the application to hang.

Comment: Add what you are asking for into your question.

Comment: Just as a side note, I am able to use GET, SET and EXISTS commands just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by setting notify-keyspace-events to Ex in the redis.conf

and listening to "`__keyevent@0__:*`"

```
jedis.psubscribe( new KeyExpiredListener(), "__keyevent@0__:*" );
```

Answer (score 2):

psubscribe is a blocking operation. You need to execute the psubscribe call on a seperate thread.